# Entity framework 4.1 : select by multiple conditions?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have an Orders class with OrderID,OrderName,CreateTime, EndTime and so on ...
Now,here is a method:

```
private TmpContext context = new TmpContext();
public List<Order> GetOrders(string id,string name,DateTime createTime)
{
      var list= context.Orders.AsEnumerable();
      if(!string.isNullOrEmpty(id))
           list = list.Where(l=>l.OrderID.Contains(id));
      if(!string.isNullOrEmpty(name))
           list = list.Where(l=>l.OrderName.Contains(name));
      // other conditions 

      return list.ToList();
}
```

### I use the Linqpad,GetOrders(2124,"Cloth"，DateTime.Now);find the sql is "select --- from Orders". It means all the Orders was Select.

What can i do with this situation. :D

Comment: Just add your next condition: ANDALSO -> `&&`, ORELSE -> `||`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `.AsEnumerable()` call.

`AsEnumerable` casts your ObjectQuery to an `IEnumerable<Order>`, which prevents the compiler from finding the correct overloads (it will use `Enumerable.Where` instead of `Queryable.Where`, because `list` is of type `IEnumerable<Order>`). That's why only the first part of the query will be sent to the server (`"select * from Orders"`), the rest will be executed in memory.

If you remove the call to `AsEnumerable`, your conditions will be correctly applied to your ObjectQuery, allowing them to be executed on the server.

Comment: @Botez3000,thanks a lot! I got what i want. But context.Orders's type is DbSet<Orders>, so i called the AsQueryable(). Everything is ok,here is anther question , How can i write this simplify and beautiful. thanks :)

Comment: @JasonGuo `DbSet<T>` already implements `IQueryable`, so you don't need to call `AsQueryable()` either. Other than that, i think your code looks fine.

Comment: :),When i call 'where',it returns IQueryable<T>,but the list is DbSet<T>.

Comment: @JasonGuo Then you can just declare list as `IQueryable<Order> list`. But i guess then it makes no difference :)